# background das divs com uma lado maior q outro

Tags: html, jquery, css, bootstrap

Boa tarde pessoal, alguem poderia me explicar por favor, como se faz esse efeito no background em declive, ou aclive, dependo do modo de se olhar.. kkk 
tentei das inspect na pagina, mas nao conseguir ver como é feito esse efeito, se é um imagem com as cores ja desse modo, ou se das divs estao com um lado maior q outro...
obg desde ja

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Há várias maneiras de fazer isso.

Você pode usar uma `div` com o fundo em gradiente. *(Recomendo)*

```
Background: linear-gradient (Ângulo, cor comprimento, cor comprimento, cor comprimento)
```

Segue exemplo abaixo.

```css
* {margin:0;padding:0}
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

body {
  background-image: linear-gradient(
    160deg,
    blue 65%,
    black 65%);
}
```

> Caso você tenha dificuldades em criar um gradiente, basta utilizar o site https://www.cssmatic.com/gradient-generator

Você também pode utilizar duas `div`. Basta utilizar `transformt: rotate(Ângulo)` e alguns valores para alterar o comprimento. *(Não recomendo)*

```css
html,body, #container, .azul, .preto {
  width:100%;
  height: 100%
}

#container {
  overflow:hidden;
}

.azul {
  background: blue
}

.preto {
  background: black;
    transform: rotate(165deg);
    margin-top: -157px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    width: 150%;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="azul"></div>
  <div class="preto"></div>
</div>
```

Ou você pode utilizar imagens.

```
background-image: url('Link da imagem');
background-size: cover; /* Informa para a imagem cobrir todo o elemento */
background-repeat: no-repeat /* Informa para não repetir a imagem. */
```

Exemplo:

```css
body {
  background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/OoXOC.png');
  background-size:cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat
}
```

Comment: muito obg amigo, vou testar aqui e ver como fica, obg mesmo!!

Comment: Só complementando a resposta, pra deixar claro ali no site, foi usado uma imagem de fundo já pronta.

Por isso não foi achado nada referente.

Parabéns pela explicação.

Comment: amigo, saberia me dizer o nome desse estilo??  pra eu pesquisar mais sobre isso? por favor

Comment: @John-Jonesentendi, muito obggg

Comment: O primeiro Exemplo, funcionou certinho!! obg

Answer (score 0):

Entrei no site do outlook, esse efeito é uma imagem um fundo dentro de uma div, pode ser nos formatos svg, png, jpg, o detalhe é que ela precisa ter no mínimo 1920px de largura para suportar a maioria das resoluções.

É só gerar a imagem e colocar como background: url();

Também é possível fazer esse efeito usando o transform: rotate(180deg);

Mas nesse caso é um pouco mais complicado porque tem q ter uma div segurando a outra que terá a rotação e será necessário algumas configurações a mais.

Comment: entendi, muito obg amigo.